# UnitTesting for EditText , testing multiple values

Tags: android, junit

Hi I am trying to test the edit Text placing  2 different values but the second test is failing .reasons unknown...below is my code
**TestCase1**

```
public void testvalues1() {
           // clearing the  edit text
            mTextView.clearComposingText();

           TouchUtils.tapView(this, mTextView);
           // sending input  as 7
           sendKeys("7");

           String userInput1;
           String expected = "158269.3778";
           String parameterFrom1 = "0.0027";
           String parameterTo1 = "61.04676";


           // getting the input from the mTextView reference
             userInput1 = mTextView.getText().toString();
             String  resultset = UnitCalculation.Converter(parameterFrom1,userInput1,parameterTo1);

           assertEquals(resultset, expected);


        }
```

In the above test case iam sending value 7 and output is as expected

**TestCase2**

```
public void testvalues2() { 
       // clearing the  edit text
        mTextView.clearComposingText();

      TouchUtils.tapView(this, mTextView);
       // sending input  as 23
      sendKeys("23");

       String userInput1;
       String expected = "150.5011";
       String parameterFrom1 = "1.092607";
       String parameterTo1 = "7.149502";


       // getting the input from the mTextView reference
        userInput1 = mTextView.getText().toString();
         String  resultset1 = UnitCalculation.Converter(parameterFrom1,userInput1,parameterTo1);
       System.out.println("printing resilt set "+ resultset1);
       assertEquals(resultset1, expected);


    }
```

**But the method is returning value 0 instead of 150.5011**
Iam using the same methos to calculate, When i give User value hardcoded like this  **String userInput1="23";** it is working, but when is taking the value from edittext its is not working.

can i send multiple values to edit text on the same testfile??

Comment: Did you leave the `userInput1 = mTextView.getText().toString();` line commented on purpose?

Comment: @Korcholis yeah tried to check giving manually..i uncommented it now

Comment: Where is **UnitCalculation** taken from?

Comment: @helleye UnitCalaculation is Util class from the actual project where it has different calculation methods

Comment: By the way I think that for every testSomething() method the activity is re-created (your setUp() and tearDown() methods are called), which would mean that you can surely send multiple values to edit text in the same test file, because you are doing it from different test cases(hopefully that was the correct name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendKeys` with more than one character is what messed it up. See [this reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#sendKeys(java.lang.String)).

To sum up, `sendKeys` needs a String which contains space separated keys. Your `sendKeys("23")`is trying to find a key in the soft keyboard called `23`, though there isn't. Try using this:

```
sendKeys("2 3");
```

As it will send these two key strokes individually, instead of trying to find a key named `23`. That's why sending just a `7` worked, because `7` is the key name for "7".

Comment: ..wow, that worked....i didn't know that we need to give as two keystrokes..thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, looks a little strange, but in the reference example they actually use `DPAD_LEFT`, which is pretty easy to recognise why using this system. Although I'd also prefer a more, java-ish way to do so, sending text as String and special keys as separate constant keys.